# Redirecting Console.Write

Tags: vb.net, redirect, console

I wrote the below-mentioned code from an amalgamation of c# tutorials about redirecting `Console.Write` or `Console.WriteLine` to a textbox text field. I realized this was bad since if I invoke any kind of `.Close()` method will erase the textbox which is the opposite of what I want to do.

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Namespace ConsoleRedirection
Public Class TextBoxStreamWriter
    Inherits TextWriter

    Private _output As TextBox = Nothing

    Public Sub New(ByVal output As TextBox)
        _output = output
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub WriteLine(ByVal value As String)
        MyBase.WriteLine(value)
        _output.AppendText(String.Format("[{0}] {1}" + vbNewLine, DateTime.Now, value.ToString()))
    End Sub

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property Encoding As Encoding
        Get
            Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
End Namespace
```

Is there anyway, besides loading a text file, that I can have all Console output redirected to either a textbox?

---

To answer a question from comments. (This code was originally found here: https://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/... But was converted over to VB)

In a separate form, the code is invoked by declaring a TextWriter.

`Private _writer As TextWriter = New TextBoxStreamWriter(frmDebugLog.txtDebugLog)`

Then as part of the `.Load` of a parent form:

```
Console.SetOut(_writer)
```

On a later portion of the form, the frmDebugLog is invoked by using `frmDebugLog.Show()`

When that window, `frmDebugLog`, is closed... that form and its textbox contents are discarded.

Comment: So, the title mentions a `DataTable` while the question mentions a `TextBox` or a `DataGridView`. You might want to proof-read your questions before submitting. Regardless, you can put whatever you want in that overridden `WriteLine` method. If you want to write to a `DataTable` then write to a `DataTable`.  If you want to write to a `DataGridView` then do so.  Just put whatever code you want executed in that `WriteLine` method.  If you want to be able to write to different destinations then you could have multiple constructors.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I thought I edited that out, noted. Another idea I had, previously, was to redirect it to a datatable. Problem was, it's the same problem... I close the object, the table gets wiped. (That and I got lost on how to set up the table in the first place.) So I focused on the textbox still.

Comment: OT: `TextBoxStreamWriter` is a bad name for that class because there is no `Stream` involved. The `StreamWriter` class is named that because it writes to a `Stream`. That class should just be named `TextBoxWriter`.

Comment: How exactly are you using that class? There's nothing about it that I can see that should cause a destination `TextBox` to be cleared as far as I can see. Maybe I'm missing something but I'd like to test it exactly as you're using it to see for myself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Edited the additional details.

Comment: What you posted was misleading. It's not "any kind of `.Close` method" but specifically the `Close` method of the form containing the `TextBox`. That's exactly what should happen. When you close a form that was displayed by calling `Show`, that form is disposed. If you want to display that type of form again, it must be a new instance and thus will not contain anything the old instance did unless you put it there. No `TextBox` is being erased. It's just a new `TextBox`.

Comment: The possible solutions are to either not dispose the form and redisplay the same instance or else store the text somewhere external to the form and restore it each time a new instance is created. Not disposing the form would mean either calling `ShowDialog` instead of `Show` or `Hide` instead of `Close`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was hoping it wouldn't come to that... And I guess if I store it as a separate string, I would just load the String via a .Load method instead. Hope I don't have to see what the limits of a variable are.

Comment: Actually, you'll need to use the constructor rather than the `Load` event handler. That's because you are writing to the `TextBox` before the form is displayed and the `Load` event handler hasn't been executed at that stage, so you would overwrite what you had put in there. I'll whip up an example and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you're using the default instance and so only ever one instance at a time.  In that case, this will do the job:

```
Private Shared txtDebugLogText As String

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    txtDebugLog.Text = txtDebugLogText
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnFormClosed(e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    txtDebugLogText = txtDebugLog.Text
    MyBase.OnFormClosed(e)
End Sub
```

By using a `Shared` field, you keep everything within the one class.  The current value of that field is loaded into the `TextBox` first whenever a new instance is created and the text in the current `TextBox` is persisted to that field whenever an instance is destroyed.